# Mosfet Vgs issues

Tags: mosfet

I am building a MOSFET bridge to make sure my signals arrive at the load in the proper polarity regardless of the input polarity. My problem is the \$V_{gs}\$ voltages on the MOSFETs are at or exceed 20 V, this is the maximum \$V_{gs}\$ MOSFET I can find. What can I do to lower my \$V_{gs}\$ while still passing 11 V signals and having the proper MOSFETs turn on/off at the right times?

Here is the circuit. Battery voltage is 11 V, and op-amps are ±10 V, any lower on the op-amps causes MOSFET M3 to saturate.

[image]

EDIT: added a more clear schematic. N-channel MOSFET \$V_T=1\$, p-channel MOSFET \$V_T=-1\$. Link to the online circuit simulation [simulation](http://falstad.com/circuit/#$+1+5.0E-6+11.086722712598126+58+5.0+50%0Av+288+256+288+208+0+0+40.0+-9.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Aw+288+256+288+288+0%0Aw+288+288+288+368+0%0Ap+560+64+560+416+0%0Ar+512+64+512+416+0+20000.0%0Af+448+176+448+144+0+1.0%0Aw+288+208+288+144+0%0Af+352+432+352+400+0+1.0%0Aw+304+400+336+400+0%0Aw+368+400+384+400+0%0Aw+480+400+480+416+0%0Aw+288+144+288+96+0%0Aw+288+96+288+64+0%0Aw+496+304+496+64+0%0Aw+512+64+560+64+0%0Aw+512+416+560+416+0%0Aa+256+224+176+224+1+8.0+-8.0+1000000.0%0Af+400+48+368+48+1+1.0%0Aw+288+64+288+16+0%0Aw+288+16+368+16+0%0Aw+368+16+368+32+0%0Aw+368+64+368+80+0%0Aw+368+80+448+80+0%0Aw+448+80+448+64+0%0Aw+400+96+400+48+0%0Aw+288+208+256+208+0%0Aw+288+256+256+256+0%0Aw+256+256+256+240+0%0Aw+176+224+176+432+0%0Ar+176+224+144+224+0+100000.0%0Aa+128+240+96+240+0+8.0+-8.0+1000000.0%0Aw+144+224+128+224+0%0Aw+144+224+144+192+0%0Ar+144+192+112+192+0+100000.0%0Aw+96+240+96+192+0%0Aw+96+192+112+192+0%0Aw+128+256+256+256+0%0Aw+96+192+96+96+0%0Aw+288+400+288+368+0%0Aw+352+208+352+160+0%0Aw+352+160+176+160+0%0Aw+176+224+176+160+0%0Aw+448+176+400+176+0%0Aw+304+400+288+400+0%0Aw+384+400+480+400+0%0Aw+400+96+96+96+0%0Aw+432+144+288+144+0%0Aw+512+416+480+416+0%0Aw+480+144+480+400+0%0Aw+480+144+464+144+0%0Aw+448+64+496+64+0%0Aw+512+64+496+64+0%0Aw+400+176+400+96+0%0Aw+288+256+384+256+0%0Aw+384+288+384+304+0%0Aw+384+304+496+304+0%0Af+416+272+384+272+1+1.5%0Aw+416+272+416+208+0%0Aw+416+208+400+208+0%0Aw+400+208+352+208+0%0Aw+176+432+352+432+0%0Ao+3+64+0+34+20.0+9.765625E-5+0+-1%0Ao+4+64+0+35+20.0+7.8125E-4+1+-1%0Ao+0+64+0+35+20.0+0.003125+2+-1%0A)

I need to keep my \$V_{GS}\$ below 20 V, and the opamp rail voltages must be equal between opamps. The voltage source can swing between ±10 V. The common is always common, so just put a negative voltage into the value box on the simulator.

Comment: You may get more responses if you draw your schematic more clearly: include designators for every component, flow signals from left to right, and specify a ground node.

Comment: Agreed, it's pretty unreadable as it is ;-)

Comment: Edited post to make the situation more clear. Check out the simulation link for an online simulation.

Comment: What about the diodes that are inside the mosfets, it looks like they will be a problem

Comment: Won't OA1 just saturate at the positive rail?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a full wave [opamp rectifier](https://sound-au.com/appnotes/an001.htm) instead of your MOSFET matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I used a series resistor (between driver and gate) + clamp zener (gate to source).